# Rolling back changes in alternative parsers in qi spirit

Tags: c++, parsing, visual-c++, boost, boost-spirit-qi

I'm having some trouble using the alternative parser, I need the parser to rollback changes if the first option failed. I tried using hold[] but I get the error that it "could not deduce template argument"

I'm trying to parse an AST, and I'm storing it in:

```
struct node;

BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_STRUCT(
    , node,
    (std::string, element)
    (std::string, category)
    (std::vector<node>, children)
    )
```

'element' is the element parsed, 'category' it's classification, and then I have a vector to store his children

So, to exemplify I have several cases similar to:

```
ABC=
    (qi::char_('a')[at_c<0>(qi::_val) = "a", at_c<1>(qi::_val) = "ABC"]
    >> B[push_back(at_c<2>(qi::_val), qi::_1)]
    >> qi::char_('c'))
    ;

ABD=
    (qi::char_('a')[at_c<0>(qi::_val) = "a", at_c<1>(qi::_val) = "ABD"]
    >> B[push_back(at_c<2>(qi::_val), qi::_1)]
    >> qi::char_('d')
    )
    ;

test = ABC | ABD;
```

B is some rule that returns a node. If I run this I get B repeated for the second alternative, since it was pushed in the first. As I said I tried:

```
test = hold[ABC]| ABD;
```

but I get that error. The solution I've come to is to store the result of rule B in a local variable and then push it only at the end of the rule (meaning the rule matches). But that results in very complicated semantic actions, any alternative?

Comment: A SSCCE helps. You can see me struggle to get a working test: https://www.livecoding.tv/sehe/

Answer (score 1):

I would say all the semantic actions are useless here<sup>[1]</sup>.

All of them can be replaced by a well-placed `qi::attr` to simply synthesize the desired attribute in-place and you can again use the automatic attribute propagation magic of Spirit.

> *In my experience, if you start using semantic actions for the simplest things, you're better of without Spirit*

### Simplify first

So, here's my take at the AST `node` type:

```
struct node {
    std::string element, category;
    std::vector<node> children;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(node, element, category, children)
```

It's functionally equivalent to yours, but more c++-like, and therefore somewhat more friendly. Now, you didn't give the rule declarations, so "imagined" them as follows:

```
qi::rule<It, node(), qi::space_type> ABC, ABD, test;
qi::rule<It, std::vector<node>(), qi::space_type> B;

// also for demo purposes:
B = '{' >> -(test % ',') >> '}';
```

Now, my suggestion of you rules, simplified:

```
ABC = qi::string("a") >> qi::attr("ABC") >> B >> 'c';
ABD = qi::string("a") >> qi::attr("ABD") >> B >> 'd';

test = ABC | ABD;
```

Indeed, you need to `hold` because /otherwise/ both ABC/ABD will bind to the same internal synthesized attribut `node&`:

```
ABC = qi::hold[ qi::string("a") >> qi::attr("ABC") >> B >> 'c' ];
ABD = qi::hold[ qi::string("a") >> qi::attr("ABD") >> B >> 'd' ];
```

This is all you wanted/needed.

### Test/Demo Program

I constructed a few test cases for the grammar as I "reverse-engi-magined" it and added debug code:

- **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb3c5358ee6cc473)</kbd>** - *with `qi::hold[]`*
- **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09dfb0add62a53dc)</kbd>** - *without `qi::hold[]`*

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>

struct node {
    std::string element, category;
    std::vector<node> children;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(node, element, category, children)

static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, node const& n) {
    return os << boost::fusion::as_vector(n);
}

static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::vector<node> const& v) {
    os << "{";
    for (size_t i = 0; v.size()>1 &&  i<v.size()-1; ++i)
        os << v.at(i) << ", ";

    if (!v.empty()) os << v.back();
    return os << "}";
}

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;

    qi::rule<It, node(), qi::space_type> ABC, ABD, test;
    qi::rule<It, std::vector<node>(), qi::space_type> B;

#if 1
    ABC = qi::hold[ qi::string("a") >> qi::attr("ABC") >> B >> 'c' ];
    ABD = qi::hold[ qi::string("a") >> qi::attr("ABD") >> B >> 'd' ];
#else
    ABC = qi::string("a") >> qi::attr("ABC") >> B >> 'c' ;
    ABD = qi::string("a") >> qi::attr("ABD") >> B >> 'd' ;
#endif

    test = ABC | ABD;
    B    = '{' >> -(test % ',') >> '}';

    for (std::string const s : {
            "a{a{}c}c",
            "a{a{}d}d",
            "a{a{}c}d",
            "a{a{}d,a{}c}c",
        })
    {
        std::cout << "\n-- Parsing '" << s << "'\n";
        It f = s.begin(), l = s.end();

        node parsed;
        bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, test, qi::space, parsed);

        if (ok)
            std::cout << "Parsed: " << parsed << "\n";
        else
            std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

        if (f!=l)
            std::cout << "Remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Output (with holds):

```
-- Parsing 'a{a{}c}c'
Parsed: (a ABC {(a ABC {})})

-- Parsing 'a{a{}d}d'
Parsed: (a ABD {(a ABD {})})

-- Parsing 'a{a{}c}d'
Parsed: (a ABD {(a ABC {})})

-- Parsing 'a{a{}d,a{}c}c'
Parsed: (a ABC {(a ABD {}), (a ABC {})})
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup>. See also [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)

Comment: Here's the recorded live  feed in case you want to know how I went about things: https://www.livecoding.tv/video/showcase-qi-hold-and-semanticactionsareevil/ ([experiment](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=24182469#24182469))

Comment: But how can I use the automatic attribute propagation if the order of the elements I am parsing sometimes does not matches the order of the struct. For example I may have an expression: `A >> operator >> B` , for instance "a+b", so the element of the node is the operator '+' and 'a','b' are his children.

Comment: You can just ADAPT_STRUCT in a different order or USE ADAPT_STRUCT_NAMED

Comment: I tried it in coliru and it works, but when I try the same code in Visual Studio 2013 with boost version 1.59, qi::hold gets the error that it could no deduce template argument

Comment: @kaladin: it may be a bug in Visual Studio 2013, can you try Visual Studio 2015